# multiple atributes with same name using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to learn react js for an internship and tried following a geeks for geeks tutorial (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-multi-page-website-using-react-js/)

[I get an error and im not sure why, the error is shown below in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz4O5.png)

Really hoping someone could help me out.

Comment: You have repeated the keyword exact twice in same router..

    `<Route exact .... exact />`

try to use it once per one route

    `<Route exact .... />`